# Prompt the user who has checked out a spreadsheet to check it back in

Tags: check-out

A couple of people have the bad habit of checking out a spreadsheet and after editing it, leave it checked-out.

Is there a way to either

- send them a message to check-in the file because someone else wants the file, or
- set up a timer to tell them they have had the file for 30min, 1hr, 2hr etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a custom Timer job and send an email to check in that files.

To check which files are checked out and who checked out :

```
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://Site URL"))
    {

    SPWeb site = siteCollection.RootWeb;

    SPList list = site.Lists["Shared Documents"];

    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items) 
    {

   if (item .File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.ShortTerm || item .File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.LongTerm)
{

   // send email or checkin

    }
    }
```

To create custom Timer jobs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Answer (score 1):

their is 3rd party web part available for this. they support 2007 / 2010 /2013. I am not sure which SP version you are.

http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/reminder/reminder-manual?p=commonscenarios%2Fleftcheckedout%2Fleftcheckedout.htm