# Email notification on doc checkout for more than 8 hours

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

How to get notified in email to 2 users when others are checking out any document more than 8 hrs. This condition should be applied to particular document library including any hierarchy in it. The information in email should be user who has checked out the document. Is it possible through designer workflow?

Comment: You might find this post is useful: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103950/prompt-the-user-who-has-checked-out-a-spreadsheet-to-check-it-back-in/103961#103961

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use server side coding. Is it possible to get calculated column to get number of hours file has been checked out?